# Prove that $Tu(x)$ is a contraction. $Tu(x) = -\lambda\int_0^1g(x,y)\sin(u(y))\,dy$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing

I want to show that $Tu(x)$ is a contraction where
$$Tu(x) = -\lambda\int_0^1g(x,y)\sin(u(y))\,dy$$ and 
$$g(x,y) = \begin{cases} x(1-y) & 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1, \\
y(1-x) & 0\leq y \leq x \leq 1. \end{cases}$$
I have 
$$\begin{align*} \|Tu_1-Tu_2\|_\infty &= |\lambda|\left\|\int_0^1 g(x,y)\sin(u_1(y))-sin(u_2(y))\,dy\right\|_\infty \\
&\leq |\lambda|\| \sin(u_1(y))-\sin(u_2(y))\|_{\infty}\left\|\int_0^1 g(x,y)\,dy\right\|_{\infty}
\end{align*}$$

I know im supposed to get that this last inequality is $\leq |\lambda|\|u_1-u_2\|\frac{1}{8}$ but I'm not sure how to show that.

Any help and comments would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just grind...

\begin{eqnarray}
|Tu(x)-Tv(x)| &\le & |\lambda| \int_0^1 |g(x,y)| |\sin u(y) - \sin v(y)| dy \\
&\le& |\lambda| \int_0^1 |g(x,y) | | u(y) - v(y)| dy \\
&\le& |\lambda| \|u-v\|_\infty \int_0^1 |g(x,y) | dy \\
\end{eqnarray}

Hence $ \|Tu-Tv\|_\infty \le |\lambda| \|u-v\|_\infty \sup_{x \in [0,1]}\int_0^1 |g(x,y) | dy $.

Now compute $\int_0^1 |g(x,y) | dy = \int_0^x y(1-x)dy + \int_x^1 x(1-y)dy = \frac{1}{2}x(1-x)$, and this is maximized at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, and so $\int_0^1 |g(x,y) | dy \le \frac{1}{8}$, which gives
$$\|Tu-Tv\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{8}|\lambda| \|u-v\|_\infty $$

(Of course, this only shows $T$ to be a contraction if $|\lambda| < 8$.)

Comment: Thank you copper.hat. I was unsure of where the 1/8 was coming from. It's much clearer now! Thanks again.

Comment: @RDev: Glad to be able to help.